# asp.net passing string variable to a user control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, properties

I am trying to pass value of a code behind variable to a user control like:

```
<pv1:ShowPdf ID="ShowPdf2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" FilePath='<%=path2%>'
        Height="700px" Width="856px" />
```

where path2 is a protected string variable declared in code behind. 
The problem is that the value of path2 is not being passed to the FilePath. What is the mistake I am making?
Simply doing <%=path2%> gives me correct value of the path2 variable on the page. 
Any help will be most appreciated.

--
Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<%=` is the same as using `Response.Write(string)`. This happens at a different point in the lifecycle than when your ShowPdf control is being built and properties being initialized - much later. Try instead using `<%#`, which sets the value during DataBind. You may need to call DataBind on your Page in CreateChildControls or some other method where `path2` is being given a value.