# Passing value to a user control from asp.net Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following user control my  `.ascx` Page. `(Test.ascx)`

```
<uc:Addresses runat="server" itemId='<%# StringId %>'></uc:SNETAddresses>
```

In the code behind of `Test.ascx` I have

```
protected string StringId = "{2A06199B-ED96-42F0-AB9A-602139E58BFB}";
```

In the code behind of user control `Addresses.cs` I have:

```
 public string itemId { get; set; }
```

So basically I want to pass a string to the variable `itemId`. But Somehow its not getting the value of variable "StringId". This simple thing is taking my so much time. I checked this post [asp.net passing string variable to a user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735747/asp-net-passing-string-variable-to-a-user-control) but I am so sorry I could not get the answer. The reply is:

```
You may need to call DataBind on your Page in CreateChildControls or some other method
```

I am new to Asp.Net and I didn't get what the user mean here.

Comment: There seems to be a typo: the start- and end-tags do not match: `<uc:Addresses ...></uc:SNETAddresses>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Page.DataBind()`, e.g. in your `Page_Load()` event handler.

Data-binding expressions (`<%# ... %>`) are only processed when you call the `DataBind()` method.

---

Alternatively (instead of using a data-binding expression), you can also simply assign the value to the user control's property from your page's code-behind:

```
// add an ID to the user control (in the markup)
<uc:Addresses runat="server" id="myControl"></uc:SNETAddresses>
```

Then in your `Page_Load()` method simply assign the value to the user control's property:

```
myControl.itemId = StringId;
```